# How to cast result from RetrieveEntityUsingPointQueryAsync as custom tableEntity in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Hello Cosmos DB Table API Team!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet

In the function RetrieveEntityUsingPointQueryAsync using C#, is it possible to replace all CustomerEntity with a generic TableEntity and then cast the result of the function call to whichever custom entity I’ve defined?

For example, I want to call:

```
PhoneEntity thisPhone = await RetrieveEntityUsingPointQueryAsync(…);
```

How do I modify this to work?  Or do I have to create a different RetrieveEntityUsingPointQueryAsync for each entity type that I have?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! What you could do is pass in a Generic Type as your Table Entity and then you can pass in whatever TableEntity Type you want like so:

```
public static async Task<T> RetrieveEntityUsingPointQueryAsync(CloudTable table, string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        try
        {
            TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);
            var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
            var returnedValue = result.Result as T;
            return returnedValue;
        }
        catch (StorageException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @user13072884 if this answer helped you, could you please mark it as answered so it can help others? Thanks :)